# Error with 'never' type when using extends keyof as generic type

Tags: typescript, lenses

My code in typescript:

```
class Author {
  id: number;
}
type Getter<S, A> = (obj: S) => A;

function propGetter<S, K extends keyof S>(prop: K): Getter<S, S[K]> {
  return o => o[prop];
}
const _id: Getter<Author, number> = propGetter('id');
```

I got error:

```
Argument of type '"id"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[Code in typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Author%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Getter%3CS%2C%20A%3E%20%3D%20(obj%3A%20S)%20%3D%3E%20A%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20propGetter%3CS%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20S%3E(prop%3A%20K)%3A%20Getter%3CS%2C%20S%5BK%5D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20o%20%3D%3E%20o%5Bprop%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20_id%3A%20Getter%3CAuthor%2C%20number%3E%20%3D%20propGetter('id')%3B)

As far as I understand, type K should be strings of keys of type S. How it's unified to never? It's because using mapped type as generic param?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't infer what's the type for `S` when you are only passing `K`.
It would work if you do this:

```
const _id: Getter<Author, number> = propGetter<Author, "id">('id');
```

Or if you change the function to receive the instance of `S` (and then it will infer the type):

```
function propGetter<S, K extends keyof S>(obj: S, prop: K): Getter<S, S[K]> {
    return o => o[prop];
}
const _id: Getter<Author, number> = propGetter(new Author(), 'id');
```

---

#### Edit

After a second thought, you can do this:

```
function propGetter<S>(prop: keyof S): Getter<S, S[typeof prop]> {
    return o => o[prop];
}
const _id = propGetter<Author>('id'); // type of _id is Getter<Author, number>
```

---

#### 2nd edit

I don't like adding code that isn't useful in the compiled js just to make the compiler happy.
This is such a case, I think that the best solution for this is something like this:

```
function propGetter<S>(prop: keyof S): Getter<S, any> {
    return o => o[prop];
}

const _id = propGetter<Author>('id') as Getter<Author, number>;
// or
const _id: Getter<Author, number> = propGetter<Author>('id');
```

This way you get type safety, in a less verbose way, and there's nothing added to the js that doesn't belong there.

Comment: Makes sense! Sadly, I can't add object as parameter to function. Would be nice, if I coul write just `propGetter<Author>('id')`

Comment: Your edit works because there's only one prop on Author. If you add for example second prop name type string, _id will have type `Getter<Author, string | number>`

Comment: I injected class constructor as argument, and typescript was able to infer type. Not perfect either. `function propGetter<S, K extends keyof S>(ctor: new(...args: any[]) => S, prop: K): Getter<S, S[K]> {
  return o => o[prop];
}` so I can call `propGetter(Author, 'id')`